Did Kamala Harris withhold evidence in a capital case?
A few years ago ten candidates vying for the Democratic Party's presidential candidacy were on a stage on live television. One of those was Kamala Harris. Another candidate said Harris had withheld evidence that would exonerate a death-row inmate when she was attorney general of California. The moderator asked Harris to respond, and instead of denying it or saying "I can explain" or the like, she changed the subject.
What is the story about this alleged withholding of evidence?

You can find the full story here: https://www.sacbee.com/news/politics-government/capitol-alert/article233375207.html

The case involves a man named Kevin Cooper, who was convicted in 1985 for a quadruple murder.
You can find a description of the incident in this Sacramento Bee article. Here's a brief summary:
While Harris was the San Francisco DA, there was a scandal involving the city's crime lab; the lead technician had been mishandling drug evidence. As a result more than 1,000 cases had to be dismissed.
The accusation is that Harris didn't disclose this problem to the defendant's counsel. Harris claims that she didn't know about the problem until it became public, so she didn't deliberately withhold this information during the trial of the death row inmate in question.
However, an opinion piece in the New York Times describes it somewhat differently. Rather than emphasizing the crime lab scandal, the issue there is not allowing DNA evidence to be used during an appeal.

This is the story of a broken justice system. It appears that an innocent man was framed by sheriff’s deputies and is on death row in part because of dishonest cops, sensational media coverage and flawed political leaders — including Democrats like [Governor Jerry] Brown and Kamala Harris, the state attorney general before becoming a U.S. senator, who refused to allow newly available DNA testing for a black man convicted of hacking to death a beautiful white family and young neighbor. This was a failure at every level, and it should prompt reflection not just about one man on death row but also about profound inequities in our entire system of justice.


Incidentally, Harris later said that she supported DNA testing of the evidence, and Brown approved the testing, shortly after the article and likely because of it, so it probably did have some import.

I'm confused.  If I'm not mistaken, Harris was 18 or 19 in 1985.  Although she's a smart woman, that would seem too young to be prosecuting in a capital case.

@gerrit The initial conviction was 1985, but the appeals would have been at later dates

Also worth mentioning that the U.S. legal system makes it very hard to revisit evidence presented at a trial in a criminal case, probably harder than any place else  in the world. A prosecutor's knee jerk reaction (too strong, but normal) is to defend the validity of convictions once entered and the law largely backs them up when they do so. She could have acted otherwise without nudging, but it would have been a very radical move for someone in her position to consider. A DA or AG conceding a point like that is national news when it happens, because it happens so rarely.
